# Isabelle: variable x occurs on right hand side only

Tags: function, recursion, isabelle, proof, isar

```
inductive S :: "alpha list ⇒ bool" where
 empty : "S []" | 
 step1 : "S w ⟹ S (a # w @ [b])" |
 step2 : "⟦S w1; S w2⟧ ⟹ S (w1 @ w2)"

inductive T :: "alpha list ⇒ bool" where
 empty : "T []" |
 step : "⟦T w1; T w2⟧ ⟹ T (w1 @ [a] @ w2 @ [b])"

fun balanced :: "nat ⇒ alpha list ⇒ bool" where
"balanced 0 w = S w"  |
"balanced (Suc 0) w = S (a # w)" |
"(balanced n w = S (a # m @ w)) ⟹ (balanced (Suc n) w = S (a # a # m @ w))"
```

I am trying to write a function `balanced` so that `balanced n w`is true if and only if `S (an @ w)` where an is list that contains `n` number of the same alphalist. For the third equation of the function`"(balanced n w = S (a # m @ w)) ⟹ (balanced (Suc n) w = S (a # a # m @ w))"` I get the error "Variable "m" occurs on right hand side only:" even though there is `m` in the left side.
The only solution that I can think of is write the function in another way but cannot think of how at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

As it stands, your definition doesn't make much sense. You're trying to fish out `m` from the result of `balanced n w`, even though the type returned is a `bool`. You can't turn that into the specific argument that was passed to `S`, just like you can't un-mince meat back into a walking chicken.

If you *really* wanted to say "if there is some `m` that satisfies this, then use that `m`", then you need an explicit existential quantifier, and then get your hands on the witness as an actual expression with the `SOME` operator. I wouldn't recommend that, though.

What you're actually trying to say, I believe, is `balanced n w = S (replicate n a @ w)`. This definition is accepted without issues (if I remembered the argument order of `replicate` correctly), but for the underlying problem of proving these two grammars equivalent, the definition won't help you.

The point of introducing the `balanced` intermediate notion in this proof is that you don't have to map a derivation tree to another derivation tree directly. What you *actually* want is a function that processes the input `w` recursively, left to right, and doesn't refer to either `S` or `T` at all. In other words, you want an *algorithm* that will decide whether the grammar matches an input. `balanced n w = S (replicate n a @ w)` is then a good thing to prove about it by induction.

Since this is an exercise (from prog-prove and/or concrete semantics, if anyone's following along at home), I won't just show you the recursive definition right now, though let me know if you get stuck with trying to get it to work.

Comment: Thank you. I understood the point of ```balanced``` wrongly and the correct way was to think what ```S``` does as well.